# How can i manage SHARING_VIOLATION error after a CreateFile c++

Tags: c++, createfile

In order to get esclusive access rights on a file i'm using the windows api:

`HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(filepath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);`

If the user by chance is using that file (i.e. a doc) with an other process the create files returns -1 as handle and set the last error to 32.

My question is the following: how can i wait until the file in no more used by other processes?
Doing something like:

```
while(handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    handle = CreateFileW(filepath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

is really stupid since it wastes a lot of resources trying and trying again.
I guess that there is a version of the api that let you block on it until it succeeds but i didn't found it in the documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API that allows you to wait for the file to be available directly. You can use [the example code from The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx) to figure out which processes currently have an open handle and then wait on those processes to exit and try again, but if the processes that have the file open close their handles early, you won't see that. Similarly, during that time, other processes may have opened the file, so you're stuck finding a new set of processes and waiting on them.

In practice, a polling loop (with a short sleep to avoid spinning constantly) is really the only way to do this. You'll want to check for more than just `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and likely want to set a maximum timeout, because looping forever when the issue is something dumb like a permissions issue or a file not found error would be a bad idea.

You may also want to look at the [file in use sample on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330722%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see about informing the user of the issue, rather than just silently polling.

Answer (score 0):

At least to my knowledge, there's no single function to do this (not particularly surprising--it could block almost indefinitely).

Since you're (apparently) targeting Win32, one obvious possibility would be to read the change journal for the target file, and only re-try opening it for exclusive access when you see that some other process has closed it (i.e., you see a USN record with `USN_REASON_CLOSE`).